# How to fix discord jda bot spam

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I'm working on a **Discord** bot but when I try to send a message to a channel, it doesn't work.

I tried to use the code `event.getChannel().sendMessage("Hello!").queue();` But this one spams my discord.

```java
public void onGuildMessageReceived (GuildMessageReceivedEvent event){
    if(event.getChannel().getId().equalsIgnoreCase("607560497083973632")){
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("Hello!").queue();
    }
}
```

This is what happens: https://prntscr.com/oo6622

Answer (score 0):

You receive your own messages. To prevent this you can just check if the received message is from the current user.

```java
@Override
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event){
    if (event.getAuthor().equals(event.getJDA().getSelfUser())) return; // ignore own messages
    if (event.getChannel().getIdLong() == 607560497083973632L){ // use long for ids
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("Hello!").queue();
    }
}
```